# How to read csv lines chunked by id-column with Spring-Batch?

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I'm using `Spring-Batch` to read a csv file, format the content and write it to a database like:

```
StepBuilder<T, T> builder = stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
    .<T, T>chunk(100)
    .reader(flatFileItemReader)
    .processor(processor)
    .writer(jpaItemWriter);
```

The csv contains an ID column. How can I modify the `reader` to base the chunks on that ID?
Examle:

```
#id, #value
1, first
1000, second
1001, second
1005, second
```

In this case the chunk would only read the first line, then commit, and then continue.

Is that possible to apply chunking by a value in the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did the same using a custom [CompletionPolicy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/repeat/CompletionPolicy.html) and a [PeekableItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/PeekableItemReader.html).
The idea behind the code is to peek next item, perfrom next element read and check from value change.
When a value change happens return `true` from `CompletionPolicy.isComplete()`.

**Important: this policy must be registered as step listener!**

```
public class BreakKeyCompletionPolicy extends CompletionPolicySupport{
    private BreakKeyCompletionContext cc;
    private PeekableItemReader<Object> reader;
    // Strategy used to check for value break
    private BreakKeyStrategy<Object> strategy;

    public void setReader(PeekableItemReader<Object> forseeingReader){
        this.reader = forseeingReader;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isComplete(RepeatContext context){
        return this.cc.isComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatContext start(RepeatContext context)   {
        context.setAttribute("current", null);
        this.cc = new BreakKeyCompletionContext(context);
        return cc;
    }
    /** Context contains current element ("current" property" and manage next element.
     * Null next element is treated as a key break
     */
    protected class BreakKeyCompletionContext extends RepeatContextSupport {
        public BreakKeyCompletionContext(RepeatContext context)     {
            super(context);
        }
        public boolean isComplete(){
            final Object next;
            try{
                next = reader.peek();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                throw new NonTransientResourceException("Unable to peek", e);
            }
            if (null == next){
                return true;
            }
            return strategy.isKeyBreak(this.getAttribute("current"), next);
        }
    }

    @AfterRead
    public void afterRead(Object item){
        this.cc.setAttribute("current", item);
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I use a `CompletionPolicy` to analyze the current textline read by the `ItemReader`? I mean, how can I get this textline within a `CompletionPolicy`? Because the last line that belongs so each batch set of records has a special indicator on a specific character position.

Comment: In my use case item was a standard POJO; with @afterRead you store the current line and with peek() you read the next. strategy object encapsulate your break key logic