# Spring Batch - Invoke read() method in Reader multiple times

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to implement calling read() method in the itemReader multiple times.

For Eg:

I have a list of POJO in which I will have one string variable with values either A or B or C.
I have to sort this list based on alphabetical order and segment it into three list for each value. i.e., list for value A and list for value B
and list for value C.

I need to send each list to the read() method in the itemReader one by one.

Once List  for A is processed and write, then I need to send List for B and so on..

Is this doable? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not very clear on what you are trying to achieve, I don't see any reason it cannot be done.

I assume you mean either of this:
1. You want the "item" to be process to be a **whole list of POJO with same ABC Type**, or 
2. You want the item to be the POJO itself, and you want them to be processed in order of ABC Type

2 is straight-forward.  At the first read, prepare all the POJOs, sort it. I assume they are in some kind of

In psuedo code, it looks like this

```
class MyReader implements ItemReader<MyPojo> {
    private List<MyPojo> values;
    MyPojo read() {
        if (values == null) {
             values = getPojos();
             sort values;
        }
        if (values.isEmpty()){
             return null;
        } else {
             return values.popFront();
        }
    }
}
```

1 is nothing more complicated.  You will need to group POJOs with same ABC type in same list, and return the lists one by one.  It can be easily done by using a `TreeMap<String, List<MyPojo>>`

In psuedo code, it looks like this

```
class MyReader implements ItemReader<List<MyPojo>> {  // note the item is List<MyPojo>
    private NavigableMap<String, List<MyPojo>> values;
    List<MyPojo> read() {
        if (values == null) {
             values = new TreeMap<>();
             pojos = getPojos();
             for (pojo : pojos) {
                 if (values do not contain pojo.abcType() ) {
                      values.put(pojo.abcType(), new ArrayList(pojo));
                 } else {
                      values.get(pojo.abcType()).add(pojo);
                 }
             }
        }
        if (values.isEmpty()){
             return null;
        } else {
             return values.popFirstEntry().value();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list of items is fully available (you have a `List<Pojo>` loaded with all items) you can:

1. use a [`ListItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ListItemReader.html) and inject into the ordered list
2. use a custom `ItemReader` and sort items after first `ItemReader.read()`

About break the best way is to use a custom [`CompletionPolicy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/repeat/CompletionPolicy.html) based on pojo 'string variable'; in this manner your writer will receive a list where POJO's 'string variable' has the same values for all list items (check [How to read csv lines chunked by id-column with Spring-Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905278/how-to-read-csv-lines-chunked-by-id-column-with-spring-batch) for sample code).