# Custom ItemReader to return more than one rows[based on some column value] to ItemProcessor

Tags: spring-batch, reader

I have a file with multiple rows. I need to read more than one rows based on some column value and pass it to Processor as List.

**Sample Input file is:**

```
2|joe|24|CA
2|sam|32|MA
2|joe|44|CA
3|amy|21|CA
```

The file is sorted based on first field.

I wanted to pass first three rows to processor as `List<item>` then last row as separate `List<item>`

Is it something we can do with CustomItemReader?

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read csv lines chunked by id-column with Spring-Batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905278/how-to-read-csv-lines-chunked-by-id-column-with-spring-batch)

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci : Thanks, i will try to understand your code and get back.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci : I gone through the class, where you are returning List<object>, i dont understand how it will return List<Object>. Can you please explain.

Comment: to do so - you have to prepare the query on the run - fetch distinct values for column 1 - then store those values in the list - and by iterating over list in your reader you can do that using where clause

Comment: `List<>` (a chunk) is returned by SB and list' size is usually equals to `commit-interval`. My custom `CompletionPolicy` doesn't return a `List<>` directly but only override the logic to split chunks; you don't care about `List<>` itself, but you need to care about how to split it.