# Spring Batch - Aggregating multiple lines in Processor

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to write an Spring Batch application that gets lots of data from a database and writes it to Excel. In this process I need to transpose some data that comes in rows into columns.
So imagine a query that returns:

```
id,name,value
1, me, 1
1, me, 3
1, me, 2
2, you, 4
3, her, 5
```

My excel would look like:

```
1, me, 1, 2, 3
2, you, 4
3, her, 5
```

Note that when transposing the lines into columns, I also sort the values, so doing this transpose in SQL is a bit tricky.
My idea was to create an ItemReader thar return each line as an object, and then in the Processor consolidate grouping lines into a single object, and an ExcelWriter that gets this DTO and writes to Excel.
To implement the Processor, I would do something like:

```
private ConsolidatedDTO consolidatedDTO = new ConsolidatedDTO();

public ConsolidatedDTO process(AnaliticDTO item) {
  if (consolidatedDTO.getKey().equals(item.getKey)) {
     consolidatedDTO.add(item);
  } else {
     ConsolidatedDTO result = consolidatedDTO;
     consolidatedDTO = new ConsolidatedDTO(item);
     return result;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm returning after consolidating everything, when I receive a different item, but how do I deal with the LAST item? I needed a way to know in the Processor when I received the last item so I could return the consolidated immediately instead of waiting for the next line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832341/custom-itemreader-to-return-more-than-one-rowsbased-on-some-column-value-to-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read csv lines chunked by id-column with Spring-Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905278/how-to-read-csv-lines-chunked-by-id-column-with-spring-batch)