# How to make input record chunk on the basis of certain value in flatfilereader in spring batch,

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have multiple records and I have to read the record on the basis of first 5 characters. Eg-

```
11111222233344555
11111222658464645
11111654521465465
32131564564654844
32131556546545646
```

In above record, I have to read the each record line by line and process it.After reading first record and processing, it will again check the first five character and see whether it is same or not for the second record. If it is same then it will again read and process it unless a different value is found before writing.It will write only when a different value is found for first 5 char like the record 4.

Comment: Do not confuse tag [tag:spring-batch] with tag [tag:batch-file], which relates to Windows batch files; please adapt the tags accordingly!

Comment: Is this a question about how to do this via Spring Batch or how do do this with a windows script file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read csv lines chunked by id-column with Spring-Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905278/how-to-read-csv-lines-chunked-by-id-column-with-spring-batch)

Comment: Spring Batch @MichaelMinella

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have records.txt in the working directory of the script, this will do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p a=<record.txt
echo %a%
set a=%a:~,5%
for /f %%# in (record.txt) do (
    echo.%%#|findstr /v /b !a!&&(
        set a=%%#
        set a=!a:~,5!
    )
)
```

When the first five digits change, it will output the line.

Comment: This will compare only the first record

Comment: Could you elaborate? record.txt contains OPs lines, and the output is 11111222233344555 and 32131564564654844 (separate lines).

Comment: If the records contain another value like 44444564564654844 !!! then your code will fail wail it will only test the first line. Its not specified in the question but for sure that can be a case.

Comment: @SachaDee Unless I misunderstand, my code will only "fail" because `4444447675 !!!` contains a space. I've tried putting `4444447675 !!!` as the first, second, third and last line. The output is the same as in your script.

Comment: You're right, sorry +1, I did'nt check it, as it is

Comment: Can anyone of you tell where to add this script? I mean in which class of my batch?

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend the `FlatFileItemReader` and introduce a field - `previousLine`.

Override the method

```
public Object read()
```

In the method call `super.readLine()` and compare with stored `previousLine`. If they have the same 5 start chars call `super.readLine()` till a different line is achieved.